# Google sheet to cloud storage

Tags: php, mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a google sheet lover, we use daily google sheet to submit & create data from sheet to sheet ( not google form to sheet ) along with google app scripts it run very fanstatics. but the problem is limit of google sheets storage, we must change the google file very often when its over limit. Anyone can advise below solution is workable since i am not expert in coding:

1. Using google app script to make data entry from google sheet ( not google form) then storage in cloud databse ( mySQL or google cloud SQL,...) directly ( not google sheet to google sheet as what i am doing to avoid limited cell of google sheet)
2. In cloud database, we can do:
   2.1 sync cloud database back to google sheet
   2.2 create/Read/Update/Delete ( CRUD ) and searcheable via web interface like PHP or HTML.

Appreciated if anyone can share if workabe in theory ? how can we start it ?

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About `but the problem is limit of google sheets storage, we must change the google file very often when its over limit.`, in the case of `In cloud database, we can do: 2.1 sync cloud database back to google sheet 2.2 create/Read/Update/Delete ( CRUD ) and searcheable via web interface like PHP or HTML.`, how do you do `sync` between Spreadsheet and such large data? Can I ask you about the detail of your question? If my understanding is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, i am not sure if we can syn large data between sheet & SQL database, but my google entry form is less data few 10-20 row for each submit. Currently my destination sheet is large data, that why i want to use destination is cloud database.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, the value from `my google entry form` is put to a database (SQL and so on except for Spreadsheet). And, you want to search and retrieve the values from the database using the new value from `my google entry form`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, Thanks Tanaike, my idea is using cloud database (2)  for both entry (1) from google sheet and CRUD (3) from web. So what i want is 1 -2-3 can sync together.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `my idea is using cloud database (2) for both entry (1) from google sheet and CRUD (3) from web. So what i want is 1 -2-3 can sync together.`.

Comment: Suppose we can syn between google sheet and cloud database, in case we need to edit / delete, we can not make it from google sheet, we must use other UI ( user interface ), i mean CRUD that why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239423/discussion-between-tu-phan-and-tanaike).

Comment: Is it possible? The answer is yes. How do you start?  Using JDBC service would be a good starting point https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc.  Personally, I've created a VPS with a REST API to query the MySQL database and fetch data from Google Sheets.